# Google Maps V3 infoWindow not opening on one page, but works on other sharing the javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am converting my website from Google Maps V2 to V3 and I'm having issues with an infoWindow popup. I have a GPS tracking website with two map pages. One is a "history" page showing a static map with all markers from a particular day for one vehicle. The other is a "live" page showing the last known location of multiple vehicles. The infoWindow works on the history page, but not on the live page. They share the same map.js file.
I have traced the script all the way to the infoWindow.open, but it just doesn't open on the live page.

Some relevant code:

```
basemap = mapstraction.getMap().setOptions({
    zoomControl: true, 
    panControl: true,
    scrollwheel: true
});
mapstraction.setMapType(mxn.Mapstraction.ROADMAP);
```

For each marker on the live screen:

```
marker.proprietary_marker.mid = currpositions["livepos"][unit]["id"];
google.maps.event.addListener(marker.proprietary_marker, 'click', googlemarkerclicked);
```

For each marker on the history screen:

```
marker.proprietary_marker.mid = jsondata["data"][markerarr][0];
google.maps.event.addListener(marker.proprietary_marker, 'click', googlemarkerclicked);

function googlemarkerclicked() {
var currmarker = this;
    var markerid = this.mid;
    //console.log('Marker id: ' + markerid + ' currmarker: ' + currmarker);
    //Handle marker click
    markerclicked(markerid, currmarker);
}

function markerclicked(markerid, markerele) {

if (pospopup_markerinfo[markerid] == undefined) {

    try {

        nocache_urladdon = "&nocache=" + new Date().getTime();
        geturl = baseurl + "&t=positionpopup&marker=" + markerid + nocache_urladdon;
        var loader = new net.ContentLoader(geturl, function() {
            eval("var jsondata = " + this.req.responseText);

            pospopup_markerinfo[markerid] = jsondata;
            //console.log(pospopup_markerinfo[markerid]);

            //Open marker info window
            openmarkerinfowindow(markerele, markerid);

        });

    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message + "\nWas trying to add marker info for specified marker " + markerid + ", try clicking refresh");
    }

} else {

    //Open marker info window
    openmarkerinfowindow(markerele, markerid);

}
```

}

```
function openmarkerinfowindow(markerele, markerid) {

//Google marker click handling
if (mapstraction.api == "googlev3") {
    //markerele.openInfoWindowHtml(genmarkerinfohtml(pospopup_markerinfo[markerid]));
    //genmarkerinfohtml(pospopup_markerinfo[markerid])
    var baloonpos = new google.maps.LatLng(pospopup_markerinfo[markerid]["lat"], pospopup_markerinfo[markerid]["lon"]);
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -20),
    content: genmarkerinfohtml(pospopup_markerinfo[markerid]),
    position: baloonpos
    });
    //console.log(pospopup_markerinfo[markerid]["lat"] + "," + pospopup_markerinfo[markerid]["lon"]);
    infoWindow.open(basemap);

}
```

Based on research, I have tried moving the infoWindow creation in and out of the marker generation function (I only need one infoWindow open at a time) while always generating the content uniquely. I have also tried with and without using markerele.infoWindow and that makes no difference. I have tested that the content and position variables are generated properly. It's got me stumped that it will open on one page no matter where I set up the infoWindow, but not at all on the other page when the code is shared.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After burning many hours on this, the solution was simple.
When calling the infoWindow.open, I needed to specify the marker.

infoWindow.open(basemap,markerele);

I don't know why it worked on one page but not the other.
So now I have moved the infoWindow creation back outside the marker creation code so only one window is created. This means as I click on different markers, the info window "moves" instead of opening multiples.

So now the code looks more like this:

```
function initgeneral() {
// Loaded once per page load
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    //pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -10),
    //content: genmarkerinfohtml(pospopup_markerinfo[markerid]),
    //position: baloonpos
    });
}
```

In the "onclick" function, now all we do is set the content and open the window, now including the markerid.

```
infoWindow.setContent(genmarkerinfohtml(pospopup_markerinfo[markerid]));
infoWindow.open(basemap,markerele);
```